# Nuxt JS Deploy on Vercel with API

Tags: express, nuxt.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy my nuxt app onto Vercel, but keep getting "Cannot GET /api/hello" or any other endpoint whenever I try to make an api request. I do not see any errors in the logs and it returns a 404 status. Everything works perfectly in my local environment.

**vercel.json:**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "api/**/*.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "nuxt.config.js",
      "use": "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder",
      "config": {
        "serverFiles": ["api/**"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
// Server Middleware API
  serverMiddleware:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? []
      : [
          { path: '/api', handler: '~/api/index' },
          { path: '/api/hello', handler: '~api/hello' }
        ],
```

**/api/hello.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json('test - get').end()
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json('test - post').end()
})

export default app
```

Comment: Does the build work locally?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine locally

Answer (score 0):

Update;

**nuxt.config.js**

```
serverMiddleware: ['~/api', '~/api/hello']
```

**/api/hello.js**

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('test-get'))
app.post('/', (req, res) => res.send('test-post'))

export default { path: '/api/hello', handler: app }
```

**/api/index.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import users from './users'

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use('/users', users)

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hi from /api'))

export default { path: '/api', handler: app }
```

Comment: serverMiddlewere: [{ path: '/api', handler: '~/api/' }],

Comment: Thanks again Shimon. Have you made any adjustments to any Vercel settings? I am still getting the error "Cannot GET /api/hello"

Comment: No, I didn't change anything on Vercel.

Comment: Could be that your /api/index.js catches all routs, and you aren't listening for /hello?

Comment: Possibly. It works with the index.js routes but not any others. How can i change my vercel.json file to allow for api/index and api/hello or any other sub directory? I've been with the testing the rewrites config but am still having trouble:
{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" },

Comment: @mike I played around, I think I got what you need.

Comment: I updated my answer above, I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Shimon, but that didn't seem to work either for me. It's not ideal, but I moved everything to the index.js file and was able to get it working.